# Where is getShippingRateGroups() defined?

Tags: module, shipping, core

We've got several extensions installed but with a recent update, we're getting an obscure error.  In certain cases, no shipping quotes are available for the customer.  We've narrowed it doen to this line:

```
    <?php if ($groups = $this->getShippingRateGroups()):?>
```

checking as false.  We look for that function to find its definition and only see calls to it in three (magento 1.6.2.0) or 5 (1.8.0.0 clean) different scripts, no where is a definition for this.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes in magento which have `Varien_Object` as a parent, make use object overloading, through the use of magic getters and setters.

Unless `getShippingRateGroups()` is defined explicitly in one of the parent classes, it will use the function `__call()` in `Varien_Object`, which will call `getData()`.

extra info:

The return value of `getShippingRateGroups()` is what `setShippingRateGroups()` has set on the object.

Search for the functions: `__call(), __get() and __set()` in the class `Varien_Object` file: /lib/Varien/Object.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php